# Greasemonkey to change value of Radio buttons in a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am writing a Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey script and I need to turn on radio buttons depending on the name and value of the radio control.

This is how it looks:

```
<input type="radio" name="11" value="XXX" class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="11" value="zzzz" class="radio">
```

So I want to set those buttons that have name of 11 and a value of zzzz to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super easy when you use jQuery.  Here's a complete script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Radio button check
// @include  http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$("input[name='11'][value='zzzz']").prop ('checked', true);
```

The `input[name='11'][value='zzzz']` jQuery selector gets all `<input>`s that have the *initial* value `zzzz`, but only if they are in the group of radio buttons with `name="11"`.

Reference:

- [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/)
- [jQuery selector documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors)
- [jQuery `.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

---

*Important:*   The above works on most pages but, **on AJAX-driven pages**, you often need to **use AJAX-aware techniques.**  This is because the Greasemonkey script will run before the checkbox you care about is loaded.

One way to deal with this is with [the `waitForKeyElements` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508). Like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Radio button check
// @include  http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("input[name='11'][value='zzzz']", selectRadioButton, true);

function selectRadioButton (jNode) {
    jNode.prop ('checked', true);
}
```

---

---

---

**Old answer** that was "state of the art" :) back when the question was asked:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            _Radio button check
// @include         http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("input[name='11'][value='zzzz']").attr ("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: This would be a lot more helpful if it included a simple explanation of what's happening and a reference to some documentation. Especially since this is such a basic question.

Comment: Even having read some tutorials in the meantime that is very helpful, I'm sure other people googling this will not have used jQuery before either. Thanks :)