# How do I run a script after internal scripts are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey, facebook-chat

I'm trying to hide specific people in the Facebook sidebar chat list.

My first attempt was to just try and replace the name of a user in the chat bar but a simple `.replace` doesn't work since the chat bar loads separately, and long after the page itself has loaded.

Is there any way of running the Greasemonkey script after the chat has loaded?

I've heard some about the `unsafeWindow` functionality, but I'm not sure if I can apply that here, and if so, how.

```
unsafeWindow.hidePerson = function() {
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Firstname Lastname/g, '' );
}

unsafeWindow.hidePerson();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question about **"Running scripts after internal scripts are fully loaded", see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508)** (the question scenario is the same as an AJAX scenario).

---

***However***, several things in your case:

1. Your issue, "`I'm trying to hide specific people in the Facebook sidebar chat list`", is already covered by Facebook!

   See ["Can I turn chat on for just a few friends?"](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=130254323719420#Can-I-turn-chat-on-for-just-a-few-friends?)
   Follow the instructions there, and you can:

   - Hide just the people you specify
   - Or, show *only* the people you designate
   - Or, turn chat off completely
2. Don't attempt to set `innerHTML` like that; you'll bust the page (Event listeners will get trashed, etc.).
3. `unsafeWindow` is a non issue here, and is not needed.
4. If you mean something that I haven't covered, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [this page](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx), and [this page](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

   Then edit your question (or ask a new one), and include, at a minimum, the HTML snippet of the part of chat you want to affect, and screenshots of the same.

Comment: Thanks Brock for your very thorough answer! Your help will come in very good use even though I don't need to apply all of it here :)