# Change source of embedded flash object in YouTube

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube, greasemonkey

I'd like to change the source swf file of a YouTube video. The video is an `<embed>` element.

### How it's built:

```
<embed width="640" id="movie_player-flash" height="390"
       tabindex="0" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       src="http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vfl07wZSq.swf" flasvars="...">
```

(An example may be found on [Google's YouTube channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/google))

I left out some attributes and the content of `flashvars` as it is a long string with settings, does this affect the video at all?

---

### What I've tried:

1. I tried by simply changing the `src` attribute, but that doesn't affect anything:

   ```
   document.getElementById('movie_player-flash').src = url;
   ```
2. I also tried to clone the original, change the source and re-append it. And again: nothing:

   ```
   var player = document.getElementById('movie_player-flash');
   var playerClone = player.cloneNode(true);
   playerClone.setAttribute('src', url);

   player.parentNode.replaceChild(playerClone, player);
   ```

Does anybody know how to accomplish changing the video source?

Comment: Could you add your `movie_player-flash` HTML, please?

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Oh sorry I forgot too mention that I am on the actual YouTube website. (it's for a greasemonkey script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many issues here:

1. The flash video is not always in `<embed id="movie_player-flash"`, sometimes it is in `<embed id="movie_player"`.  Since this is Google, there are probably other schemes as well.
   So, a simple `document.getElementById('movie_player-flash')` is right out. Use something like:

   ```
   var flashEmbed  = document.querySelectorAll ("#movie_player-flash, #movie_player");
   if (flashEmbed.length) {
       flashEmbed  = flashEmbed[0];
       // DO THE SWITCH HERE.
   }
   ```
2. *Just* changing the `src` attribute **does** work, but only in rare circumstances.  If you are switching to a different video that:

   1. **Requires no parameters.**
      (Although you might be able to restore these by creating the appropriate `<object>` and `<param>` tags.)
   2. **Loads no external dependencies.**
      These will be blocked by cross-domain security, if they are not on the same domain as the target page.
      Additionally, the paths of objects a flash file loads are often fixed within the file itself (Possibly giving 404 errors, even if same domain).

   **Then, it can work.** See [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgUnR/1/).
3. Re:

   > I left out some attributes and the content of `flashvars` as it is a long string with settings, does this affect the video at all?

   On modern Youtube, the `flashvars` are everything!  Also, if you compare the `src` attribute, you'll see that it is the same for most all flash videos.  For example, no matter what video I try, currently the `src` is `http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vfl07wZSq.swf`.

   That's because the flash object, loaded by the the `<embed>` tag, is not the video.  It is a shell object that loads the player (and other things), and the player loads the actual video file.

   So, nominally, **to change one Youtube video into another, you must change the parameters and/or `flashvars`**.  Even if you change the `src` to an old-style, direct `<embed>` link (EG: `http://www.youtube.com/v/uY3LAFJbKyY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0`), it will only appear to work until the ***Play*** button is pressed.  Then the video as defined in the parameters will return and play.
4. **However,** Youtube still preserves aspects of the old system (for now).  So, if you can find the old-style embedding link, you can swap the `src` to that and replace the `<embed>` with one that has no `flashvars`.  See the code at the end of the answer.

   Here's one way to find the old-style embedding link:

   1. On the video's Youtube page, press the ***Share* button**.
   2. Press the ***Embed* button**.
   3. Check the ***Use old embed code* checkbox**.
   4. The textarea will now display `<object>...<embed>...` HTML.  Copy that out and extract just the `<embed>` `src` attribute.  (EG:

      ```
      http://www.youtube.com/v/uY3LAFJbKyY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0
      ```

      )
      Discard everything else.
5. The flash element does not always load right away.  It can also be replaced via AJAX.  So, we may need to wait for the (right) `<embed>` to appear.
   For simplicity, I'll show this with `setInterval()`, but for a robust, practical solution, you'll want to use [the `waitForKeyElements()` utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891), as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

Putting it all together, here is a **complete Greasemonkey script** that swaps out most videos:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _Youtube, replace flash video
// @description Replaces most videos with the Greatest Video Of All Time!
// @include     http://www.youtube.com/watch*
// @include     http://www.youtube.com/user*
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var embedChkIntval  = setInterval ( function () {
        var flashEmbed  = document.querySelectorAll ("#movie_player-flash, #movie_player");
        if (flashEmbed.length) {
            var playerClone = flashEmbed[0].cloneNode (true);
            playerClone.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0';
            playerClone.removeAttribute ("flashvars");

            flashEmbed[0].parentNode.replaceChild (playerClone, flashEmbed[0]);
            clearInterval (embedChkIntval);
        }
    },
    150
);
```

Comment: Man, this is amazing! Thank you so much for your very good answer and the detailed insight. I really can work with this.
Haha, and I've been rick roll'd, well done! :)