# Add event on dynamic change of DIV

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

I have a page (Facebook page) that has its content changing dynamically. I am writing a GM script but it only loads when the page refreshes, and this is not the case. I have tried to do something like:

`mydiv.addEventListener('load', myfunc() ,false );`

as I saw in a different thread, but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: what is `mydiv` supposed to be?

Comment: A div I find using document.evaluate(...) of other function.

Comment: is the console reporting anything?

Comment: I don't know, usually when a GM script is broken it just stops executing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval()` or [the waitForKeyElements utility](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11195658/331508).

Can't give any more detail unless you provide specifics like: what, ***exactly***, you are trying to do; before-and-after HTML; or even a link to the page and/or screenshots.

Comment: Here it is: I am trying to use GM in a Facebook page, so that if a div with role of article (ie the usual content) has a certain property, its style is changed (background color for instance). This works fine when I just enter Facebook or refresh a page. But, since in Facebook when I click on links I do not turn to another page, but rather just change the content of a dynamic div (the contentMain I believe), I need to figure out how to run my GM function after such a change, and not just after a refresh.

Comment: waitForKeyElements does things like that.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't it performing this by busy-waiting? ie a loop that will cause the page to be pretty heavy?

Comment: No it uses timers to check a few times per second.  You could have hundreds of these timers going (you'll use only one) and not notice any performance decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Change `myfunc()` to `myfunc`.

Using `myfunc()`, you are calling the function.
While `myfunc` is just passing the reference to your function.