# Replace Facebook thumbnails in a RSS Reader (InoReader)

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey, rss-reader

I'm looking to create a Greasemonkey script that will replace Facebook thumbnails in InoReader or any other RSS reader. Previously I had been successfully using the script below in Google Reader, but it doesn't work in InoReader, Feedly, or any non-Google RSS Reader.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             greader-facebookurlreplacer
// @name           Google Reader - Facebook URL Replacer
// @version        1.1
// @namespace      
// @author         
// @description    
// @include        https://www.google.com/reader/*
// @include        https://www.feedspot.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("chrome").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (e) {
if (e.target.tagName && e.target.tagName == "DIV" && /entry\s?/.test(e.target.className)) {
    var t = e.target.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var n in t) {
        var r = t[n];
        if (/.*akamaihd\.net.*_s\.\w+$/.test(r.src)) {
            r.style.width = r.style.height = "inherit";
            r.src = r.src.replace(/_s\.(\w+)$/, "_n.$1")
        }
    }
}
}, false)
```

I also tried using the following code retrieved from a similar post on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work either in InoReader.

```
$("img[src^='https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net']")
.each(function()
{ 
  this.src = this.src.replace(/(\/[^/]*)s\.jpg$/, '/s720x720$1n.jpg');
});​
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is a sample feed that has these images?  Provide the HTML structure the image is in.  Are iframes involved?

Comment: @BrockAdams Here is a link to part of the HTML containing the Facebook thumbnail portion extracted with Firefox's inspector. [Link](https://www.box.com/s/cse8ihadyoaj7m1lak80) Doesn't seem like iframes are involved.

Comment: I also changed the original question to apply to InoReader instead of Feedspot, but both seem to work the same.

Comment: A sample Facebook RSS feed containing the small thumbnail images would be https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=24810773606&format=rss20

Comment: Thanks for providing the site links; it really helped with the specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMNodeInserted` is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events)  Don't use that approach anymore.  Best to use a utility like [waitForKeyElements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

After that, it's just a matter of finding the right [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for the images, and then the right regex to convert the `src` to the one for the larger image size.  (But note that some sites deliberately make the regex approach impossible.)

For [the sample RSS feed you listed](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=24810773606&format=rss20), on [inoreader.com](http://www.inoreader.com/), we can [use Firebug to determine a CSS/jQuery path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15052467/331508) to the thumbnails of:

```
#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img
```

For the `src` changes/regex, see the code.

Here's how to replace the images, for that feed, on that reader:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _InoReader thumbnail replacer
// @include  http://www.inoreader.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements (
    "#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img",
    swapOutFbcdnThumnails
);

function swapOutFbcdnThumnails (jNode) {
    /*-- Change src from:
        https://fbcdn-photos- ... _s.jpg
        to:
        https://fbcdn-sphotos- ... _n.jpg
    */
    var newSrc      = jNode[0].src.replace (/fbcdn\-photos\-/, "fbcdn-sphotos-");
    newSrc          = newSrc.replace (/_s\.jpg$/, "_n.jpg");
    jNode[0].src    = newSrc;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I just had to change the @include to https and inoreader.com/* (instead of www.inoreader.com/*) for it to work. What if I wanted to include Flickr thumbnails without using a separate script? I used a modified version of your code [here](https://www.box.com/s/y3b1fn4z27wa1zu12ibz). It works, but I'd like to combine it with the above to use in a single script instead of having a separate script.

Comment: All you need to do is use `if()` statements, inside `swapOutFbcdnThumnails()`, to test the `src` URL to determine which type of regex to apply.  Ask a new question if you need to.

Comment: Figured out the regex required to change Flickr thumbnails, but don't know how to include them in if() statements. I apologize as my Javascript knowledge is sparse. I posted a separate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439306/replace-tumblr-pinterest-flickr-images-with-larger-versions-in-inoreader-rss) regarding combining everything into a single script. [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439306/replace-tumblr-pinterest-flickr-images-with-larger-versions-in-inoreader-rss)

Comment: Also I referenced the script you wrote above in that question. Unfamiliar with the etiquette here and was wondering if you'd like me to credit your name for the scripts.

Comment: Don't need credit. (Just votes. ;) )  Looking at your new question now.