# Replace Tumblr, Pinterest, Flickr images with larger versions in InoReader (RSS Reader)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, rss-reader

I'm looking to make a Greasemonkey script that will replace the images in Tumblr, Pinterest, Flickr, Facebook, and Webstagram RSS feeds with larger versions in [InoReader](https://www.inoreader.com/).

I had been successfully using the following scripts in Google Reader for Tumblr and Pinterest. Would like to port them over to InoReader and combine them all into a single script.

Old Google Reader **Tumblr** script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Big Photos from Tumblr on Google Reader
// @include        http://*.google.com/reader/view/*
// @include        https://*.google.com/reader/view/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("chrome").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (e) {
if (e.target.tagName && e.target.tagName == "DIV" && /entry\s?/.test(e.target.className)) {
    var t = e.target.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var n in t) {
        var r = t[n];
        r.style.maxHeight = "1080px";
        var i = r.src;
        if (i.indexOf("tumblr") > -1) {
            r.src = r.src.replace("_500.jpg", "_1280.jpg");
            r.onerror = function () {
                this.src = this.src.replace("_1280.jpg", "_500.jpg")
            }
        }
    }
}
}, false)
```

Old Google Reader **Pinterest** Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             greader-pinteresturlreplacer
// @name           Google Reader - Pinterest URL Replacer
// @version        1.3
// @include        https://www.google.com/reader/*
// ==/UserScript==

document.getElementById("chrome").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (e) {
var t = e.target;
if (t.tagName && t.tagName == "DIV" && /entry\b/i.test(t.className)) {
    var n = t.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var r in n) {
        var i = n[r];
        if (/pinterest\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test(i.src) || /pinterest\.com\/192x\//.test(i.src)) {
            i.style.width = "inherit";
            i.style.height = "inherit";
            i.src = i.src.replace(/_b\.(\w+)$/, ".$1");
            i.src = i.src.replace(/\.com\/192x\//, ".com/550x/")
        }
    }
}
}, false);
document.getElementById("chrome").addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (e) {
var t = e.target;
if (t.tagName && t.tagName == "DIV" && /entry\b/i.test(t.className)) {
    var n = t.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var r in n) {
        var i = n[r];
        if (/pinimg\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test(i.src) || /pinimg\.com\/192x\//.test(i.src)) {
            i.style.width = "inherit";
            i.style.height = "inherit";
            i.src = i.src.replace(/_b\.(\w+)$/, ".$1");
            i.src = i.src.replace(/\.com\/192x\//, ".com/550x/")
        }
    }
}
}, false)
```

---

---

The following are working Greasemonkey InoReader scripts for Facebook, Webstagram, and Flickr.

InoReader **Facebook:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             inoreaderfacebookthumbs
// @name           InoReader Facebook Thumbnail Replacer
// @version        1.0
// @include        https://inoreader.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

/* Facebook Thumbnails */ 
 waitForKeyElements (
"#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img",
swapOutFbcdnThumnails
);

function swapOutFbcdnThumnails (jNode) {
/*-- Change src from:
    https://fbcdn-photos- ... _s.jpg
    to:
    https://fbcdn-sphotos- ... _n.jpg
*/
var newSrc      = jNode[0].src.replace (/fbcdn\-photos\-/, "fbcdn-sphotos-");
newSrc          = newSrc.replace (/_s\.jpg$/, "_n.jpg");
jNode[0].src    = newSrc;
}
```

InoReader **Webstagram:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             inoreaderwebstagramthumbs
// @name           InoReader Webstagram Thumbnail Replacer
// @version        1.0  
// @include        https://inoreader.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

/* Webstagram Thumbnails */ 
waitForKeyElements (
"#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img",
swapOutWebstgmThumnails
);

function swapOutWebstgmThumnails (jNode) {
/*-- Change src from:
    https://*.amazonaws.com ... _6.jpg
    to:
    https://*.amazonaws.com ... _7.jpg
*/
var newSrc      = jNode[0].src.replace (/amazonaws/, "amazonaws");
newSrc          = newSrc.replace (/_6\.jpg$/, "_7.jpg");
jNode[0].src    = newSrc;
}
```

InoReader **Flickr:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             inoreaderflickrthumbsreplacer
// @name           InoReader Flickr Thumbnail Replacer
// @version        1.0
// @include        https://inoreader.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

/* Flickr Thumbnails */ 
waitForKeyElements (
"#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img",
swapOutFlickrThumnails
);

function swapOutFlickrThumnails (jNode) {
/*-- Change src from:
    https://*.staticflickr ... _m.jpg
    to:
    https://*.staticflickr ... _b.jpg
*/
var newSrc      = jNode[0].src.replace (/staticflickr/, "staticflickr");
newSrc          = newSrc.replace (/_m\.jpg$/, "_b.jpg");
jNode[0].src    = newSrc;
}
```

Here are some sample RSS feeds for each: [Tumblr](http://automotivated.tumblr.com/rss), [Flickr](https://secure.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=22980156@N03&lang=en-us&format=rss_200), [Pinterest](https://pinterest.com/smashingmag/feed.rss), [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=122944654424930&format=rss20), [Webstagram](http://widget.stagram.com/rss/n/voguespain/)

How do I merge these scripts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget the older 2 scripts. They use `DOMNodeInserted` [which is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Mutation_events).

Merging the InoReader.com scripts is easy.  They all use the same selector for `waitForKeyElements()`, so merely use `if()` statements to determine which regex to apply in the callback function.

Something like this should do it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        InoReader Thumbnail Replacer
// @version     1.0
// @include     http://inoreader.com/*
// @include     http://www.inoreader.com/*
// @include     https://inoreader.com/*
// @include     https://www.inoreader.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (
    "#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content a.underlink img",
    swapOutThumbnails
);

function swapOutThumbnails (jNode) {
    var imgSrc      = jNode[0].src;

    //-- The necessary regex changes depending on where the images are hosted.

    if (/staticflickr/.test (imgSrc) ) {
        /*-- Change src from:   https://*.staticflickr ... _m.jpg
                          to:   https://*.staticflickr ... _b.jpg
        */
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace (/_m\.jpg$/, "_b.jpg");
    }
    else if (/amazonaws/.test (imgSrc) ) {
        /*-- Change src from:   https://*.amazonaws.com ... _6.jpg
                          to:   https://*.amazonaws.com ... _7.jpg
        */
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace (/_6\.jpg$/, "_7.jpg");
    }
    else if (/fbcdn\-photos/.test (imgSrc) ) {
        /*-- Change src from:   https://fbcdn-photos- ... _s.jpg
                          to:   https://fbcdn-sphotos- ... _n.jpg
        */
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace (/fbcdn\-photos\-/, "fbcdn-sphotos-");
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace (/_s\.jpg$/, "_n.jpg");
    }
    else if (/pinimg\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test (imgSrc) || /pinimg\.com\/192x\//.test (imgSrc) ) {
        /*-- Change src from:   http://*.pinimg.com/192x/...
                          to:   http://*.pinimg.com/550x/...
        */
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace(/\.com\/192x\//, ".com/550x/");
    }
    else if (/pinterest\.com.*_b\.\w+$/.test (imgSrc) || /pinterest\.com\/192x\//.test (imgSrc) ) {
        /*-- Change src from:   http://*.pinterest.com/192x/...
                          to:   http://*.pinterest.com/550x/...
        */
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace(/\.com\/192x\//, ".com/550x/");
    }

    jNode[0].src    = imgSrc;
}

/* Tumblr */
waitForKeyElements (
    "#reader_pane div.article_full_contents div.article_content img", swapOutThumbnails2
);

function swapOutThumbnails2 (jNode) {
    var imgSrc      = jNode[0].src;
    if (/tumblr/.test (imgSrc)) {
        imgSrc      = imgSrc.replace (/_500\.jpg$/, "_1280.jpg");
        jNode[0].addEventListener ("error", tumblrImgErrFix, false);
    }
    jNode[0].src    = imgSrc;
}

function tumblrImgErrFix () {
    this.src        = this.src.replace ("_1280.jpg", "_500.jpg");
    console.log ("*** Img Err fix.");
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I added the additional statements to convert the Pinterest thumbs and that's working fine.

The Tumblr part works only if the "_1280.jpg" version exists. How do you add the .onerror condition that was in the original Tumblr script to return the "_500.jpg" if "_1280.jpg" isn't there?

Comment: Okay, the updated answer should do it.  I added your suggested edit changes too.  *Important:*  The first answer had a potential error.  I changed how this new version sets the `src` to fix that.