# Tampermonkey script only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, tampermonkey

Basically when I go onto a youtube page tampermonkey says the script is running, but it isn't. After I refresh the page it works fine though.

I have found a few other [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995540/force-tampermonkey-to-run-execute-script-late) with a similar issue and they used waitForKeyElements. However I don't fully understand how this works and can't manage to make it work myself.

The script i'm making can be found [here](https://github.com/ljfed/Better-YouTube-Scrolling/blob/master/better-youtube-scrolling.js)

I tried surrounding everything with a function

```
betterYoutubeScrolling()
{ 
  // code 
}
```

and adding

```
waitForKeyElements ("#movie_player", betterYoutubeScrolling);
```

to the beginging.
After doing this I get following error in the console.

> "ReferenceError: waitForKeyElements is not defined"

I can't find any other information about waitForKeyElements or any other method of solving the issue so any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Recall Tampermonkey script when page location changes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32277150)

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much solves my problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recall Tampermonkey script when page location changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275387/recall-tampermonkey-script-when-page-location-changes)

Answer (score 1):

In the post you linked, checkout that you did include:

```
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
```