# Greasemonkey code to put Youtube iFrames in spoiler

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, embed, greasemonkey

On a forum that I'm a member of we have a large number of threads which end up having a lot of Youtube videos embedded on, and quite a lot of people find this quite annoying when scrolling down the page. So, I would like to use Greasemonkey to wrap a spoiler each one so each video can be opened and viewed separately.

Here is code that's used for one video as an example;

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/_IATqru7Sh8?wmode=opaque" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="300" width="500"></iframe>
```

And I'd like to wrap some code around it so that every video is contained in a Javascript spoiler that has a button to be clicked to show the video.

I've managed to replace simple text with Greasemonkey but this one is a bit complicated for me. Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not too hard using the awesome power of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [the waitForKeyElements utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

1. Use `waitForKeyElements` to find iframes with `youtube.com` in their `src`. waitForKeyElements is AJAX-aware.
2. Replace each found `<iframe>` with a `<button>`, after marking the iframe as found (using the `gmSpoiledAlready` class in this case).
   The button also stores a copy of the iframe's source code so the the iframe can be recreated.  We don't just hide the iframe, because then it could still load things in the background -- which slows the page down.
3. Use jQuery's `.on()` to activate all of the buttons.  When clicked, each button will replace itself with it's original iframe source.

Here's **a complete Greasemonkey script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Hide iframed youtube videos
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
waitForKeyElements ("iframe[src*='youtube.com']", hideYoutubeVideo);

function hideYoutubeVideo (jNode) {
    if ( ! jNode.hasClass ("gmSpoiledAlready") ) {
        jNode.addClass ("gmSpoiledAlready");

        var srcCode     = jNode[0].outerHTML;

        jNode.after ('<button class="gmYT_hide">Show YouTube video</button>');
        jNode.next ('button').data ("frmCode", srcCode);
        jNode.remove ();
    }
}

//--- Activate any and all of the spoiler buttons
$(document.body).on ("click", "button.gmYT_hide", restoreYoutubeVideo)

function restoreYoutubeVideo (evnt) {
    var jThis   = $(evnt.target);
    var frmCode = jThis.data ("frmCode");

    jThis.replaceWith (frmCode);
}
```