# Code works in console/scratchpad but not in a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'm trying to write a script to make the map larger on [Google Flights](http://www.google.com/flights/).

I've got the jQuery working in the Firefox scratchpad.  This script does exactly what I am trying to accomplish:

```
$('div').filter(function(){ 
   return $(this).css('width') == '648px'
}).css({"width":"900px","height":"550px"});
```

but when I paste that into a Greasemonkey script, it doesn't work.  If I add some console.logs to debug, I can verify that the script is running and the filter is working correctly, but it's not modifying the CSS.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometime you will need to make sure the script is executed after that the page was loaded

```
$(function(){
   // YOUR CODE HERE
});
```

You can also try with setTimeout and put 2sec (2000)

```
var myfunc = function(){
  // YOUR CODE HERE
};
setTimeout(myfunc, 2000);
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  My function was loading and running before the map was initialized, even though the document was ready.

Comment: Often times, waiting for a fixed interval will not give repeatable, reliable results (unless you set the delay to a very large, annoying value).  There are techniques and [the `waitForKeyElements` utility](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508) for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Content added by AJAX-driven pages is often added long after your userscript runs, so the script does not normally see it.

You can use a long, fixed, interval as shown in Kursion's answer, but that has drawbacks:

1. Choosing the delay value is problematic.  And if the page is slow to load for the usual reasons, a fixed delay is likely to be inadequate.
2. Making a longer delay will still not always work and slows/stops your userscript for annoyingly long periods.
3. An very dynamic pages, a `setTimeout` will only catch the *first* instance, at best.  Subsequent nodes will be missed.

**A better way is to either use `MutationObserver`s or a utility like [waitForKeyElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).**
Both have advantages and disadvantages, but I've found `waitForKeyElements` to be simpler and more robust in general. <sup>(Disclosure: I wrote it.)</sup>

Here is **a complete userscript** showing the question code factored to work on dynamic web pages:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Fix div CSS on AJAX-driven pages
// @match    http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("div", adjustSelectDivdimensions);

function adjustSelectDivdimensions (jNode) {
    if (jNode.css('width') == '648px') {
        jNode.css( {"width": "900px", "height": "550px"} )
    }
}
```