# Is there any way to inject code into a website via vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869204/userscript-is-there-a-way-to-inject-jquery-code-into-angularjs-dom) in stackoverflow, which is a bit similar but did not help me.

I would like to find some extension/plugin for vscode that would inject a JS and CSS code into a given URL.

For example, after setting a url in vscode, I create a js and when saving the file this script is injected into **google chrome** in the url mapped or in the tab that is open in chrome.

There is an extension to chrome that does just that: [User JavaScript and CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld)

Comment: Hey, have you found/created an extension that does just that? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is non-trivial but definitely possible.

I sadly cannot provide you with all the necessary information as I am not sufficiently familiar with the way VSCode extensions function.

First of all, there is [this project which you should take a look at](https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli). It's source code will have useful information.

Alternatively, and my personal recommendation, you should go with abusing the remote debugger which chrome provides. [This project is a good example of how it can be used](https://github.com/sidorares/crconsole). It connects to the chrome remote debugger and exposes a REPL.

There is [readily available documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-evaluate) on how to use the remote debugger to execute arbitrary javascript.

The next part will be to make an actual extension which takes the above, ties it together and listens to a "on file save" event or something of the sort.