# Can't access elements by Id, class name, etc. in a new (AJAX) window?

Tags: javascript, iframe, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

The target page has a button that opens a new window:

```
<img src="resources/icons/3.png" id="iconImage_3"  
    ondblclick="window.newWindow(3,this.alt,'../messagesBox.aspx?view=inbox&amp;',false,true,null,null,null,null);"
>
```

I need to access stuff in that window but I'm having a hard time.  I get error messages as commented, below, in my script code.

And, I can only find info online regarding `window.open`, and not about `window.newwindow`.

---

## Update:

With the help of a SO user in chat, we learned that `window.newWindow` actually creates a "dialog" <div> containing an iframe with the content I want to manipulate. (Element `id="messageHeader_6328087"`, for example.)

---

Here is my code:

```
var messages;
var g=0;
function list() {
    var p = document.getElementById("messageHeader_6328087");

    var aclickEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    aclickEvent.initEvent('click', false, true);
    p.dispatchEvent(aclickEvent);
// getting can't click on null 
    var r = document.getElementsByClassName("even unread");
    var s = document.getElementsByClassName("odd unread");
    var msgeven = Array.prototype.slice.call(r, 0);
    var msgodd = Array.prototype.slice.call(s, 0);

    var k = Math.max(msgodd.length,msgeven.length);
    confirm(k);
// this gives 0, so I'm not sure if when returned null they just automatically put     //nothing
    var i = 0;
    while (i < k) {
        if (i< msgeven.length) {
            messages.push(msgeven[i].id);
        }
        if (i< msgodd.length) {
            messages.push(msgodd[i].id);
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    alert(messages.length);
    // am getting can't take length of undefined, am I using push wrong?
}
```

How do I click that button?

Comment: Any chance you could add me chat? I'd be glad to share the link to the website with you but prefer not to in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-click that image (`#iconImage_3`), the target page creates an `<iframe>` that contains the content you are looking for.  CSS is used to make it *look* like a new window.

This is an AJAX scenario. That iframe does not exist when the page loads and your userscript runs.  You need a way to make your script wait for that iframe. One easy, robust way to accomplish this is to use [the waitForKeyElements() utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

For example, visit [this Dynamic Iframe test page on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/xuwosovi/1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready (jQueryMain);
        function jQueryMain () {
            //--- If this is the iframe, change the content.
            if (/BeAnIframe/i.test (location.search) ) {
                $("body").html (
                    '<h4>This is iFrame content</h4>' +
                    '<button id="generateMessageBtn">This is the button to click via userscript.</button>'
                );
                $("button").click ( function () {
                    $("body").append ('<p>Button was clicked.</p>');
                } );
            }
            else {
                $("button").click ( function () {
                    $("body").append (
                        '<div><iframe src="' + location.href + '?BeAnIframe=1"></iframe></div>'
                    );
                } );
            }
        }
    </script>
</head><body>
<p>Click the button below, and then the userscript will click the button that appears in the iframe.</p>
<p><button>Open the iframe below.</button></p>
</body></html>
```

It looks like this:

> [image: test page before user action]

Then, when you click the button, it looks like this:

> [image: test page after user action]

The iframe and contents were added via AJAX.

A simple Tampermonkey, or Greasemonkey, script to click that iframed button is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Dynamic iframe content clicker
// @include http://jsbin.com/xuwosovi/*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant   GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
if (window.top == window.self) {
    //-- Only runs if it's not an iframe.
    waitForKeyElements (
        "#generateMessageBtn",
        clickMessageButton,
        false,
        "iframe[src*='BeAnIframe']"
    );
}

function clickMessageButton (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

Note that:

- `#generateMessageBtn` is the [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for the iframed button.
- `iframe[src*='BeAnIframe']` is a jQuery selector for the iframe itself, keying off the `src` attribute which is important for your particular situation.

Go ahead and install that script and then visit [the test page](http://jsbin.com/xuwosovi/1).  When you click the first button, You'll see a message indicating that the second button was clicked by the userscript.

---

---

Now, **for your specific scenario**, A script like this *should* click the indicated node.  (We can't test it.)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    Dynamic iframe content clicker
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant   GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
if (window.top == window.self) {
    //-- Only runs if it's not an iframe.
    waitForKeyElements (
        "#messageHeader_6328087",
        processMessageWindow,
        false,
        "iframe[src*='messagesBox.aspx?view=inbox']"
    );
}

function processMessageWindow (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

If that works, this question is answered. Open a new question for additional problems, but you should be able to populate your variables `r` and `s` by modifying `processMessageWindow()` like so:

```
function processMessageWindow (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);

    var frameBody   = jNode.parents ("body");
    var r           = frameBody.find (".even.unread").get ();
    var s           = frameBody.find (".odd.unread").get ();

    // Add additional processing here...
}
```

Note:

- `.parents()`, `.find()` and `.get()` are jQuery functions.
- You can't use `document.getElementsByClassName` for this. `document` still points to the parent window, not the iframe.

Comment: Whelp just got confused for a second, never mind haha, will take some time to look up all the features involved, thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck.  Probably out to delete your 1st comment.  Keeps it neater.

Comment: - I "managed" to open the message box in a new tab all by itself, basically just opened the source, how come it's still an iframe? It's the only thing on that page.

Comment: BOOM, pressed a messaged by ID in that new tab with the source!

Comment: I can chat now for just a bit. It's unclear what these comments mean.

Comment: After seeing how much effort Brock put into this and how complicated it is I got desperate to find something else, hopefully I'll be able to pull info by opening it in a new tab. Regardless, I will pick up every bit of the answer and thank you for spending so much time chatting and helping me even after I keep saying misleading and stupid things!