# Userscript to hide a child node of a cross-domain iframe

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I want to hide the comments with some words inside by a (Tampermonkey) user script. As an example, I tried to apply a script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Hide CNN
// @match      http://www.cnn.com/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @run-at document-end
// ==/UserScript==

$('div.post-body:contains("Abbas")').hide()
```

to the page http://www.cnn.com/2014/07/08/world/meast/mideast-tensions/index.html?hpt=hp_t1 with the following code for posts

```
<div class="post-body">
 <header>
 ...
 </header>
 <div class="post-body-inner">
 <div class="post-message-container" data-role="message-container">
 <div class="publisher-anchor-color" data-role="message-content">
 <div class="post-message " data-role="message" dir="auto">
 <p>Abbas is nothing but puppet dog of Western savages and Nazis who want to enslave entire world.</p>
 </div>
 ...
</div>
```

But the script does not seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible at all to filter a dynamically-loaded part of a webpage with a user script?

UPD: The problem is that comments are loaded in the iframe from another domain. How do I hide a child  node of such an iframe with Tampermonkey? Do I need to use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` somehow?

Comment: What is likely happening is that when your script runs, Disqus has not yet loaded. I think what you would need to do is bind it to a suitable event - possibly the `load()` event (http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). If you try running the same command from the developer console, it looks like it should work, it's just seems likely that it's running at the wrong time.

Comment: Hmm. Even on a fully-loaded page with comments executing `$('.post-body')` in the developer console returns `null`, although selecting nodes frome the main article, e.g. `$('.cnn_storypgraphtxt')`, works as expected...

Comment: #disqus_tread is empty at all when the page is loaded. The content is dynamically generated by AJAX. You will need to use a MutationObserver to recognize when new content has been added. Even window.onload will not be fired when AJAX content is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disqus*-powered comments are typically loaded in an <iframe>. So rather than set your script to run on the main site, you set it to run on the iframe `src` URL.  In this case, `http://disqus.com/embed/comments/...`

Also, these comments are AJAX driven. So you must use [AJAX savvy techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508).

A script like this should work (selector might need tuning):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Hide select CNN comments
// @match    http://disqus.com/embed/comments/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//--- Only run on comments for CNN pages
if (/&f=cnn&/i.test (location.search) ) {
    waitForKeyElements ('li.post:contains("Abbas")', hideComment);
}

function hideComment (jNode) {
    jNode.hide ();
}
```

Comment: good answer. How can it also identify the main document URL and ensure it is only run on the CNN page with those Disqus comments?