# Need help selecting & changing height of a div id in an iFrame using JQuery in a Tampermonkey userscript

Tags: jquery, iframe, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to change the height of a div id inside in iFrame from 226px to 660px.  Yes, the iFrame source is from the same domain.

I'm trying to select div id `dojox_grid__View_1` inside iFrame id `finesse_gadget_1`.  I've tried the solution with the highest votes from here:

- [How to get the body's content of an iframe in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript)

But it didn't work.  So, I ran this command:

```
console.log($("iframe#finesse_gadget_1").contents().find("#dojox_grid__View_1"));
```

And this is the result:

```
jQuery.fn.init [div#dojox_grid__View_1.dojoxGridView, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#dojox_grid__View_1"]
```

But, I don't understand what it means?

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="finesse-container">
   <div id="finesse-gadgets-workspace">
      <div id="panel_home">
         <iframe id="finesse_gadget_1">
            <html><body>
               <div id="teamBody">
                  <div id="teamRoster">
                     <div id="hideFocus">
                        <div id="dojoxGridMasterView">
                           <div id="dojox_grid__View_1" style="height: 226px;"></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </body></html>
         </iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The only way I can successfully select the iFrame is like this (`document.getElementById` didn't work):

```
$('iframe#finesse_gadget_1', parent.document.body)
```

Here's the code that I've tried, without success:

```
var iFrame = $('iframe#finesse_gadget_1', parent.document.body);
var iFrameDocument = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document;
var iFrameContent = iFrameDocument.getElementById('#dojox_grid__View_1');
iFrameContent.height(660 + 'px');
```

I've also tried this, without success:

```
$('iframe#finesse_gadget_1', parent.document.body).contents().find('div#dojox_grid__View_1').height(660 + 'px');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

1. Determine if the iframe is on [the same domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) as the web page.  What is the iframe's `src` parameter (or is it missing)?  What is the page's URL?
2. Wait for the iframe to load.

#### If the iframe is same domain:

Then use a technique like [`waitForKeyElements`<sup>Link</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508) to get the desired node.
Here is a complete working script that shows that:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Change iframed div, same domain
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

//-- Use the optional iframe selector of WFKE.
waitForKeyElements ("#dojox_grid__View_1", changeHeight, false, "#finesse_gadget_1");

function changeHeight (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("height", "660px");
}
```

---

#### If the iframe is NOT same domain:

Then **set the userscript to run on the iframe's domain** and, again, use `waitForKeyElements`:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Change iframed div, different domains
// @match    *://IFRAME_SERVER.COM/IFRAME_PATH/*
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements ("#dojox_grid__View_1", changeHeight);

function changeHeight (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("height", "660px");
}
```

Comment: Hi Brock, I'm getting this error in TamperMonkey:  `waitForKeyElements  is not defined`

Comment: @Tom, you need to use the code **exactly** as shown, changing nothing but the `@match` line at first.